# How can i post the information in the realtime firebase database without the id?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to send the info to my firebase realtime database. But in the database, the username info is posted with the id and It should be posted without the id, at the same place as the email. I tried different solutions like using put or parse instead of a post but when doing this, it deletes the email.
Anyone knows how can this be solved?

First, for the email, I use the method crearPerfil() and to post the username I use the method crearUsername().

```
Future<bool> crearPerfil(UserModel email) async{

final url = '$_url/users.json';
final resp = await http.post(url, body: userModelToJson(email));
final decodedData = json.decode(resp.body);
print(decodedData);
//TODO VERIFICAR IS USER YA ESTA EN FIREBASE
decodedData.forEach((id, key){
  
 keyUser = key;
 print(keyUser);
});

return true;

}

Future<bool> crearUsername(UserModel user) async{

final url = '$_url/users/$keyUser.json';
final resp = await http.post(url, body: userModelToJson(user));
final decodedData = json.decode(resp.body);
print(decodedData);
//TODO VERIFICAR IS USER YA ESTA EN FIREBASE

return true;

}
```

![Here the image of what it does in firebase][1]
[There's what happens when I try with put][2]

```html
UserModel userModelFromJson(String str) => UserModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String userModelToJson(UserModel data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class UserModel {
    UserModel({
       // this.id,
        this.email,
        this.username,
        this.instagram,
        this.paypal,
        this.linkedin,
        this.twitter,
        this.youtube,
        this.snapchat,
        this.phonenumber,
        this.link,
        this.fotoUrl,
    });

    //String id;
    String email;
    String username;
    String instagram;
    String paypal;
    String linkedin;
    String twitter;
    String youtube;
    String snapchat;
    String phonenumber;
    String link;
    String fotoUrl;

    factory UserModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => UserModel(
       // id         : json["id"],
        email      : json["email"],
        username   : json["username"],
        instagram  : json["instagram"],
        paypal     : json["paypal"],
        linkedin   : json["linkedin"],
        twitter    : json["twitter"],
        youtube    : json["youtube"],
        snapchat   : json["snapchat"],
        phonenumber: json["phonenumber"],
        link       : json["link"],
        fotoUrl    : json["fotoUrl"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
      //  "id"         : id,
        "email"      : email,
        "username"   : username,
        "instagram"  : instagram,
        "paypal"     : paypal,
        "linkedin"   : linkedin,
        "twitter"    : twitter,
        "youtube"    : youtube,
        "snapchat"   : snapchat,
        "phonenumber": phonenumber,
        "link"       : link,
        "fotoUrl"    : fotoUrl,
    };
}
```

Comment: Calling `post` is defined as creating anew child node, so there the behavior you see is expected. If you get the same with `put`, please edit the question to show that code, and the before and after JSON from your database.

Comment: I just edited it

Comment: You're still calling `post`, and as said: `post()` is expected to create a new child node under the URL where you call it. If you want to write the data to the exact location and replace what's there, use `put()`. If you want to write to the exact location, but merge with other existing keys, use `patch()`.

Comment: Also: nothing changed in your edit, so you might want to check. To prevent struggling with images: it is much better to post content as text where possible. Here it is possible, because JSON is just a text format. You can get this for your database by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Hello i tried with put but when i do this it puts the info without the key in the correct place but it delette the other info that is contained in this place

Comment: That is the expected behavior for a `put` request. If you want the data to be merged with the existing keys in the same location, use a `patch` call.

Comment: When I use patch it also remplaces the info by the new info

Comment: It's impossible to say what's happening without seeing the updated code, the JSON before the write operation, and the JSON after it. Please edit your question to include those.

Comment: I just added the json file